# IO Exception: "/root/test outside /opt/h2/DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

currently I installed the H2 database, but when I the launch the program and I try to access it from my browser (http://localhost:8082/login.do), I get this error:

```
IO Exception: "/root/test outside /opt/h2/DB" [90028-192] 90028/90028 (Aide) org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "/root/test outside /opt/h2/DB" [90028-192]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.setBaseDir(ConnectionInfo.java:182)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:114)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:102)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:735)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.login(WebApp.java:955)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:211)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:170)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:133)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How I can fixe this ?

Comment: which version of H2 database u r using

Comment: I'd check any configurations for that `/root/test` value.

Comment: I use this version: h2-1.4.192

Answer (score 8):

Just add a single "." before the name of your database. For example this is the jdbc url for my database: `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9101/~/test` and I'll change it to this to work: `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9101/~./test`. I've read in a forum that this bug relates to H2.

Comment: Do you know where you saw this bug mentioned? There is little to find about this bug when I Google for it. I am using version 1.4.197 (2018-03-18) and this issue is still there. Nobody else has this problem?

Comment: When I wanted to cluster H2 I faced this issue and I could not connect to my jdbcurl. After a little search I found this bug in earlier versions of H2 and when I added "." the issue resolved. My version was "h2-1.4.195".

Answer (score 1):

you should change the form jdbc url
and the `h2-data` which is you start h2 server data path

```
jdbc:h2:/h2-data/test
```

Comment: You may get this exception when you run H2 as docker container, in which case h2-data is the base data directory, so changing your URL to something like jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/h2-data/test should work for you.